# How to do a pairwise interchange of rows in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a sequence in an matrix (computed from sortrows function in Matlab). Say the matrix looks something like this after computing:

```
A = [5; 3; 4; 1; 2];
[b, c] = size(A)
```

In lieu of performing permutations on the sequence in A, I would like to peform a pairwise interchange of the cells, so the performance runs better, even though the results won't be exact (it will be very close to answer though). I want the rows to look somewhat like this in the end =>

```
A1 = [5; 4; 3; 2; 1];
A2 = [4; 5; 3; 1; 2];
A3 = [4; 3; 5; 2; 1];
A4 = [3; 4; 5; 1; 2];
```

Now, the catch is that the matrix will contain as little or as much elements (it will vary). Matrix 'A' is just an example. How do I perform [b-1] pairwise interchanges on A (or any other matrix)?

Comment: Can you please explain how `A1` through `A4` are obtained more thoroughly?  I don't see the pattern.

Comment: Even I can't see any pattern and FYI, the matrix `A`, you are referring to actually seems like a column vector.

Comment: There really is no pattern through A1 and A4, I am just trying to perform pairwise interchange on the numbers that are next to each other.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar you are correct, it is a column vector, although it can be a row vector as well

Comment: @Lyssa - That really doesn't answer my question, and I still don't see how you got those vectors.  My apologies for sounding ignorant.  Please describe explicitly what you mean by "pairwise interchange".  Simply showing examples isn't enough for someone (not as intuitive) like me.  Think of me as a child.  How would you describe what "pairwise interchange" is to a child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = [5; 3; 4; 1; 2];

swapIndexLeft  = [1,2,3,4,5];
swapIndexRight = [2,3,4,5,1];

%// make sure the dimension of indices agree
assert(numel(swapIndexLeft) == numel(swapIndexRight))

%// ... and values do not exceed dimensions of the vector A
assert(max(swapIndexLeft)<=numel(A) )
assert(max(swapIndexRight)<=numel(A) )

%// swap iteratively
for ii = 1:numel(swapIndexLeft)
     temp = A( swapIndexLeft(ii) );
     A( swapIndexLeft(ii) ) = A( swapIndexRight(ii) );
     A( swapIndexRight(ii) ) = temp;
     %// now you have an array where the element swapIndexLeft(ii)
     %// has been swapped with swapIndexRight(ii)

     %// do your calculations here
end
```

Comment: +1 - For figuring out what the OP wanted before the OP lol.  Good job!